# Using callback in exe between DLL instances

Tags: c++, winapi

I've written a C++ exe that binds my DLL to Windows Hooks, which entails injecting an instance of the DLL into each process. So you have 1 exe, and 1 or more DLL instances at any time.

I know in a DLL you can use `#pragma data_seg(...)` and a linker comment to share data between DLLs but the caveat is that you may not share pointers this way for obvious reasons (dynamic memory addresses, pointer offsets etc)

However, might I go in the opposite direction? That is, have a callback function in the exe that the DLLs can invoke? The theory being that if I can define this function location as 'fixed' in memory in the exe, it should be safe for any DLL instance to call it?

Is this possible? I'm worried that the exe is too low level for such an approach.

If not, is there any mechanism I can use to share a single callback function between multiple DLL instances?

Many thanks

Comment: Hard to guess how a callback function is related to shared memory in a DLL.  Sounds like you're trying to call a function in another process.  That's a no.

Comment: Essentially yes, that's the idea. I don't want to have to use a service/REST api etc so maybe its back to the drawing board. Was trying to avoid making the injected DLL too heavy with business logic

Comment: You are making your life miserable by using a *very* awkward way to communicate between processes.  Shared memory is just that, memory, it provides no help at all with the synchronization that is required.  A named pipe is much easier to get going.

Comment: I'm open to alternate approaches, but if you have one you should post it as an answer so it may get the credit.

Comment: I'm just guessing at it.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Um, I guess you're talking about Local Procedure Call.. How about making your .exe COM Server? It may be simple than using LPC..

Comment: I use a COM server in some of my EXEs, it works well for interop when other processes need to communicate with an EXE. The only catch is if you have multiple instances of the EXE running. So you might need to design your EXE to only allow one instance to run at a time.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot put a function pointer into the shared segment.  You would still be accessing a process-local memory address across process boundaries, and that is not good.

What you can do instead is have the EXE put an `HWND` it owns into the shared segment.  An `HWND` can be shared across process boundaries.  That way, multiple instances of the DLL can send a message to that HWND when needed, and the EXE can process those messages as it sees fit to do.